# Div not centering on certain browsers

Tags: html, css, firefox, margin, center

Over the past few weeks I've been developing a website for a friend of mine and while it works perfectly in most browsers, it breaks in 2 seperate ones.

I have a div, with css of

```
#div2 {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

In Chrome, Opera, Internet Explorer and many other browsers, it loads fine, and centers the div.
But in Firefox and Safari (Both on windows), the div stays on the left of the page.

div2 IS inside a parent div, but the parent div only has a border set on it, nothing else.

I've been trying for ages to rectify the issue, even using the @-moz-document url-prefix() css, but it still doesn't fix it.

Any suggestion would be gratefully recieved.

Comment: please recreate in jsfiddle including the parent div

Comment: Post the HTML to your question.

Comment: do you reset the css first?

Comment: Make sure your parent div has width 100%.  If something else in the page is forcing it to be less than the page width, then the inner div would be centered within the parent div, but the parent div would not stretch across the screen resulting in it looking like it is not centered...

Comment: @DavidFleeman you could still use `position: relative` on the parent to make it use 70% of the _available_ space.

Comment: @DavidFleeman `width: auto` instead of `width: 100%` will avoid some problems. See [the difference between width:auto and width:100%](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201112/the_difference_between_widthauto_and_width100/)

Comment: @FelipeAls - good link/post, width:auto is better.  Basically, my point to the user, make sure the width of your parent div is sufficient for the behavior you are wanting to achieve in those browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying "width: 100%" on the parent div.  This same issue happens when there isn't a container div, and the solution is specify "html, body {width: 100%}", so this is likely the same case.

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, add `text-align: center` on the parent div

Comment: This is a good solution, providing you can use 100% width div...ie, not covering any buttons that would make them unclickable.

Comment: This fixed it.
I'd commented out the parent divs width during a test and forgot to reinstate it. So a really big oversight on my part there.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
{
left:50%;
margin-left:-200px; //minus half of your div width
}
```

Comment: That's really bad for dynamic content and should be a resort for vertical centering.

Comment: Doesn't explain why OP code wouldn't work in Firefox; `margin: 0 auto` is still a better method in many cases

Comment: Dynamic content can be controlled with javascript. Get the new width and adjust margin-left as needed.

Answer (score 0):

A Firefox moderator already gave a solution:

```css
#div2 {
    border: thin solid #000000;
    width: 760px;
    height: 1px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```